# WordpressMu network with private sites

Tags: multisite, private

Anyone know a way to have WordpressMU to work like this:

New user registers an account and thus is registered for the whole network (default functionality in WP Multisite), but then he/she would be required to "ask" for an access for the sites within the network one by one. The network home page would be accessible for everyone, but the subsites should be private.

So in essence, the user has one username and password for the whole network, but in order to view the site, the user has to be given rights to do so site by site basis by the admin of the site.

Any ideas? Plugins? Anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By deafault, any sub-site is open to public. You would need to add code to check if a user is logged in. And if user is logged in, does he have the right priviliges?

What I would do, is to create one new `role` for each sub-site. Then when a new user registers, I would manually add the right sub-site role to the user, thus giving him access to the site.

You can use the members plugin for managing roles: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/

Comment: Sounds good, got to look for ways to make it automated, but the idea itself should work. Thanks a bunch!